# Javascript Buffer Array has data but logs as undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, buffer

I want to make a check-condition`if()`-case if the Buffer Array is filled, then continue, if not do something `else`. But Javascript has got me on its finest.

If I try to log the whole object with the BufferArray containing, it logs:

```
{"type":"Buffer","data":[137,80,78,71,13,10,26,10,0,0,0,13,73,72,68,82,0,0,1,94,0,0,1,94,8,2,0,0,0,66,73,224,77,0,0,80...]
```

When I now try to log only the buffer array like so:

```
logger.info('Data is: ' + JSON.stringify(someObj.data))
```

The result is:

```
Data is: undefined
```

What are we doing wrong here? And how can i If-check if a buffer-array is empty or has data?

Comment: check if the somObj.data is undefined or null before apply stringify.
if(someObj.data) console.log(JSON.stringify(someObj.data))

Comment: We did this and if the array is filled it still does not log the buffer array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to type:

```
JSON.parse(someObj.data)
```